# PHP image upload with proper order

Tags: php, html, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a simple script for eCommerce website that uploads images for products.

```
<input type="file" name="pictures[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

Everything works absolutely fine, and multiple images are uploaded at once.

However, there's one major problem. **Script (or Win10 I am using) doesn't not remember which image I clicked first.** It doesn't 'remember' the order. For internet stores it's extremely important to keep main image main - so main image should be a specific image out of the set of these images.

What's the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

- you just shouldn't count on the browser for it, try make two fields with different name attribute like :

```
    <input type="file" name="main" />
    <input type="file" name="pictures[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't leave that to the browser, as there is no standard order that's guaranteed.

What you need to do is to use two different fields:

```
<input type="file" name="mainpicture" />

<input type="file" name="pictures[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

Comment: I'm using this approach now, but is there's a way to upload all at once? I think I've seen a lot of uploaders that allow this. Upload a bulk of images at once and main one will be the main one. Craigslist, Ebay come to mind.

Comment: The problem lies in the interface: how do you tell the system which image is the main, when "pictures[]" means, in fact, "bunch them all together in no particular order"?

A different interface might well be able to manage this (I don't think eBay uses plain vanilla input file fields -- I might be mistaken, though).

Otherwise you need to either check the images themselves (e.g. find the largest?), or restrict the users to those browsers where the $pictures[0] actually corresponds to the first *clicked* image, and not the *earliest* or the *first in lexicographic order*.

Comment: >or restrict the users to those browsers where the $pictures[0] actually corresponds to the first clicked image  - that's what's needed. How to make sure which browser does what? It's for inner script for adding products to store, so it's not for users, just for website content creator(s).

Comment: The best way would be to experiment. Then, check that `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ` matches what you're expecting (because the backend people WILL use a different browser than what you told them to. You have my word on it).